# How to update Oracle Timestamp value from the current to a timestamp from the past

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an Oracle Table called `EVENT_TABLE_T`. It has a column called `LAST_UPDATE_DT`. One sample value from this column is: `01-JUL-13 11.20.22.37448900 AM`. There are over 700 rows that have this same timestamp value.
I would like to update this value to 45 days before this date, using a SQL statement.
For example,`01-JUL-13 11.20.22.37448900 AM`, after my mental arithmetic, should become: `15-May-13 11.00.00......` (exactly 45 days).
If this is successful, I would like to apply an update on a different value in `LAST_UPDATE_DT` that reflects a value that goes back back 46 days.

What I hope to accomplish by asking this question is to be able to learn the basics of Oracle dates and timestamps and apply them to my batch processing work.
I would like to be able to run this update sql statement from Oracle SQL Developer and also from inside a Java `PreparedStatement.`

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can simply subtract a time interval from the timestamp.

```
UPDATE EVENT_TABLE_T 
SET LAST_UPDATE_DT = last_update_dt - interval '45' day
WHERE LAST_UPDATE_DT = TO_TIMESTAMP('01-JUL-2013 11:20:22:37448900','DD-MON-YYYY HH24: MI:SS:FF')
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Ravi's answer got me off in the right direction and Arban complemented your answer.

Answer (score 5):

Try something like:

```
    UPDATE EVENT_TABLE_T 
SET LAST_UPDATE_DT = TO_TIMESTAMP('15-MAY-2013 11:00:00:00','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS:FF')
WHERE LAST_UPDATE_DT = TO_TIMESTAMP('01-JUL-2013 11:20:22:37448900','DD-MON-YYYY HH24: MI: SS:FF')
```

similar for the update you want for going back 46 days.

Check for syntactical error if any

Comment: Your statement works to set (update) my current date to a certain date in the past. Not exactly what I wanted, but I gained another important concept from your answer. Appreciated.